# UWP GridView Table

Tags: gridview, html-table, win-universal-app

I would like to make like a table in HTML. So I get some data from my database.

Each item is a `User`. The user has a username, firstname, lastname and email. And I want to make a table to list this users.

Each user have to be on a new line. I have already search on internet, but didn't find anything like I want.

If someone can help me, it will be very nice.

Comment: Please follow the tutorials to understand (https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls)  the UWP application development. This will help you in further development of your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following skeleton code and build around it (such as adding relevant GridView attributes such as border thickness/color, width, etc. and of course populating data binding from your database). Likewise, attributes for the Grid in the data template.

The code behind for the xaml below is not shown as it contains no user code but page initialization which is added automatically.

This code is tested and works.

```
<Page x:Class="Sample.GridViewTestPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:data="using:Sample.Data"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <data:UserDataCollection x:Key="userDataCollection"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <GridView ItemsSource="{StaticResource userDataCollection}"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  IsSwipeEnabled="true"
                  SelectionMode="Single">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The following is the UserData class model and the UserData object collection for binding. It's easy to figure out.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Sample.Data
{
    class UserDataCollection: ObservableCollection<UserData>
    {
        public UserDataCollection()
        {
            // Sample data loaded here. Replace with data from your database

            this.Add(new UserData() {
                UserName = "user1",
                FirstName = "FN1",
                LastName = "LN1",
                Email = "user1@nowhere.local" });

            this.Add(new UserData() {
                UserName = "user2",
                FirstName = "FN2",
                LastName = "LN2",
                Email = "user2@nowhere.local" });

            this.Add(new UserData() {
                UserName = "user3",
                FirstName = "FN3",
                LastName = "LN3",
                Email = "user3@nowhere.local" });
        }
    }

    public class UserData
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh great thank's man, and if I want to add a header to this table, how can I do ? I just want to add a title to each column.

Comment: Just make the first row data your column names. In above replace the first data sample corresponding to "user1" with column names. Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah I understand what you are saying, but there is not a better way to do that ?

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to use `this.Add()`. The error message is `Non-invocable member 'ClassName.Add' cannot be used like a method.`. Please help.

Comment: You do need to set specific widths though, `Width="Auto"` doesn't neatly line up in columns.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add the column names using StackPanel as follows and
giving each TextBlock same width as Column Width and choosing TextAlignment as
center

```
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock
                Width="200"
                Text="UserName"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                />

            <TextBlock
                Width="200"
                Text="IMEI"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Width="200"
                Text="FirstName"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Width="200"
                Text="LastName"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Width="200"
                Text="Email"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                />

        </StackPanel>
```